# Preprocessor and subsitution of format string

Tags: c, string, c-preprocessor, scanf, format-string

If I put:

```
#define SIZE 10
```

and after:

```
scanf("%SIZEs", s);
```

I have a runtime error. The preprocessor should substitute `SIZE` with `10` before to compile, so this should equal (in my opinion) to write

```
scanf("%10s", s);
```

so, where is the mistake?

Comment: The pre-processor does not look inside string or character literals.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to replace the contents of the string literal by macro.
For example, it does the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define S_(x) #x
#define S(x) S_(x)

#define SIZE 10

int main(void){
    char s[SIZE + 1];
    scanf("%" S(SIZE) "s", s);
    puts(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the problem is in

```
  scanf("%SIZEs", s);
```

Anything residing between the quotes `" "` of a format string (*string literal*, in general) will not get substituted through MACRO substitution.

So, your `scanf()` remains the same as you're written, after preprocessing, and `%S` (or, `%SIZEs`, in whole) being one invalid format specifier, you get into  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and hence got the error.

You can try the workaround as

```
 scanf("%"SIZE"s", s);
```

This way, `SIZE` will be outside the quotes and will be considered for substitution in preprocessing stage.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SIZE only for formatting, you can also use:

```
#define SIZE "10"
scanf("%"SIZE"s", s);
```